# sign in with wechat feather for my application.

Tags: java, web-applications, integration, using, wechat

I want sign in with wechat feather for my application. I am unable to find any sample code or help document for integration with wechat. Please help me out on the same topic.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://dev.wechat.com/ for details on the WeChat SDK for iPhone and Android